# Rails RGeo::Geos.supported? false on rails c, but true on irb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis, geos, rgeo

I'm using the rgeo gem which gives me troubles on the production server, although it works on my local machine.

This outputs are same on both local MacOS and Ubuntu 16.04 production machine:

`psql --version -> (PostgreSQL) 9.6.15`

`geos-config --version -> 3.7.1`

`SELECT postgis_full_version();` returns:

```
 POSTGIS="2.3.3 r15473" GEOS="3.7.1-CAPI-1.11.1 27a5e771" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.3, released 2015/09/16" LIBXML="2.9.3" LIBJSON="0.11.99" TOPOLOGY RASTER
```

But in `rails c` the production machine returns:
`RGeo::Geos.supported? => false`
although `irb` returns `RGeo::Geos.supported? => true`

Any advice is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For others with this problem, `spring stop` and restart rails console could be enough if you installed everything correctly

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, `RGeo::Geos.supported?` was true in irb but false in rails console in Production.

I am using Capistrano with rvm. Root cause was both were different ruby(s). Rails console was using bundler's ruby and irb was using rvm's ruby.